# Prediction that a Employee can take a leave or not based on his previous track record

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

which prediction algorithm should I use to find the probability that an employee takes leave and come back on the specified period(i.e.does does not extend his leave).

Thank You.

Comment: Add a minimal example of what you have already tried to your post and explain what is not working.